# Solve a Cipher, Fight a War

Tags: cipher, steganography

The war against the dastardly General Hoggquill has been going very poorly indeed.  He has had every tactical advantage, and we survive only by the skins of our teeth.

However, this night we've had a stroke of luck!  Our scouts have intercepted a message headed for his front lines!  If we knew what their orders were, we'd at last have the upper hand!  Huzzah!

It reads:

```
01|03|03|01|16|17|00|01|03|00|31|01|17|31
01|12|12|01|16|17|00|01|12|00|01|01|17|17
01|16|16|01|16|21|00|01|16|00|01|01|10|21
01|12|12|01|16|17|00|01|12|00|01|01|10|17
31|03|03|31|31|31|00|31|03|00|31|31|08|31
```

Well, what are their intentions?

Comment: Welcome to puzzling

Comment: Thank you very much! I hope this turns out to be a fun puzzle.

Comment: My first thought was number to letter, but it has the number 31 so no.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil: Why not? There are no digits 8 or 9.

Comment: There are up to 31 days in a month? Might have something to do with a calender. (Wait nvm there's a 0. Also, 31 in base 8 is 25, so... Hm)

Comment: @MOehm, 26 letters in an alphabet

Comment: @MOehm The second to last number in the bottom row is 08.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil: yes I know. I though the numbers could be base 8, so that 00 to 31 maps to 0 to 25, but I hadn't seen the 08 in the second but last cell. So, yeah.

Comment: it use just 9 numbers 01,03,16,17,00,31,12,21,09

Comment: @JamalSenjaya you missed "10"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The numbers are ...

> ... just decimal numbers from 0 to 31, i.e. 5-bit numbers. Therefore, each column between vertical bars represents a 5×5 pixel grid:
>
>  [image: decoded pixel grid]

This is ...

> ... the [Pigpen or Masonic cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigpen_cipher) and the message is:
>
>  ATTACK AT DAWN.
>
>  (There are some transcription errors, though: The 08 should probably be a 04 and the wedge for the T points the wrong way. It is also questionable whether the message is actually helpful to the intercepting party, since "Attack at Dawn" is the cryptographer's version of "Test, test! One, two, test!")

Note:

> It is enough to see that there are only so many different columns in the code. You can then assign a unique letter to each column pattern, `abbacd ab fagh` in this case, and try to find a suitable substitution cipher, for example by using the cryptogram solver [quipquip](http://quipqiup.com/index.php). That's how I found the message. I then worked back from that to find the whole pattern.